# Canonical Q&A needed: Assumptions with patterns

Tags: discussion, site-organization

As I just discovered while gathering Related links this question comes up again and again in one form or another:

- [Assumptions on unknown functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6182/121)
- [Simplify equations with pattern assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42607/121)
- [Simplify using functional equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42901/121)
- [Problem with general assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58271/121)
- [Unknown function with arbitrary arguments assumption](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67343/121)
- [Simplify with assumption of unknown function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79301/121)
- [Assumptions with patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79756/121)
- [Is it possible to add some pattern to $Assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94983/121)
- [Assumption on the range of a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123881/121)

I think we clearly need a canonical Q&A that addresses this issue from multiple angles and in depth, ranging from the simplistic "No, Assumptions does not support patterns" to advanced techniques to work around this limitation.  We should also identify any other related questions and close as duplicate those for which it is appropriate.

Who is up for taking point on this?

Comment: <Crickets>. I think this is a great idea and would be willing to do it, but I don't know nearly enough about it, I think. Do you think this belongs as its own Q&A or as a new answer on the [pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) post?

Comment: @march It seems like a lot of people see the value in this but nobody wants to take charge of it.  (Much like [(1801)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1801/121))  I am not sure what can be done about that.  In any case this needs its own Q&A as Pitfalls is specifically to *Focus on non-advanced uses* and this would be far from basic, IMHO.